# Remove discount code from customline Items in commercetools

Tags: commercetools

I've added a discount code and successfully applied a discount to the customlineItems using the addDiscountCode API call(https://dev.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-carts.html#add-discountcode) and all the prices are calculated and the discount is applied successfully.

But when I remove the discount code using the removeDiscountCode API, the discounted amount is not removed. Furthermore if I add a product to cart after removing the discount code, the discount is not applied to subsequent products.

My Question is which API is used to remove discount from a cart which contains customLineItems?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `removeDiscountCode` https://dev.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-carts.html#remove-discountcode to remove the discount code from the cart.

Once the discount code is removed from the cart, the discounted amount in the cart will be removed and there will be no further discounts for subsequent products too.